# How to build @Url.Page link with queries in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to build page link with @Url.Page() to some page with some query params
like "/somepage?page=1".
Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it usual use case? Like `Url.Page("somepage", new { page = 1})`?

Comment: But don't work, the result is "/somepage?handler=1"

Comment: Then check your controller or route

Comment: You should be more specific about the actual URL that you want to generate, including providing any information about handlers associated with the page, and any route template that you might have defined.

Comment: I using Razor Pages :)

Answer (score 0):

this may help:

```js
var ConfirmRegistration = Url.PageLink(pageName: "/Account/Confirmation", values: new {userId = Id, code = ConfirmationCode}));

return ConfirmRegistration ;
```